# Append variable at end of URL - PHP

Tags: php, url, variables, append

I want to append the variable $name to the URL http://google.com/script.php so that I can call the variable in another script.

How do I modify the following code without having those syntax errors?

Thanks.

Codes:

```
$name = $_GET['smsname'];
$call = $client->account->calls->create('+103632', $number,                                             
        'http://google.com/script.php'
    );
```

Comment: You have not accepted any of the 15 questions, you have asked.

Comment: @user1581579 Is the below answer you were hoping for? Please accept!

Answer (score 5):

Append it like so

```
$name = $_GET['smsname'];
$call = $client->account->calls->create('+103632', $number,                                             
        'http://google.com/script.php?name='.$name
    );
```

And in the next page you can get it using `$_GET['name']`

Answer (score 3):

Just concatenate it using `.`

`$var1 = 'text';` `$var2 = 'text2';`

Concatenation = `$var1.$var2;`

In your case.

```
$name = $_GET['smsname'];
$call = $client->account->calls->create('+103632', $number,                                             
        'http://google.com/script.php?name='.$name;
    );
```

But, you should validate `$name` for values, as in if it is empty or not. 
Because, that code of yours will only works if if `script.php?name=` has a value, but if it is not, then you should be prepared to do something instead. like this:

ex: `$name = isset($_GET['smsname']) ? $_GET['smsname'] : 0;`

The above code pretty much says, if `script.php?name=` is set to some value, then assign it to `$name` else `$name` should be `0`

The  `: 0;` part, is there to set a value of `0` IF nothing is set or if `$_GET['smsname']` is empty. You can add anything you like there