# Store URL into variable and then pass into header redirect - PHP

Tags: php, variables, redirect, header

I am getting syntax errors and so I need some help.

I am using PHP to redirect the user

```
header( 'Location: http:/domain.com/' ) ;
```

Edit: I want to store the URL to this page into a variable and then append that URL to the location in the header.

For example, the user goes to http://www.domain.com/permalink I want to store '/permalink' into a variable and then pass it into the header so that the user is redirected to http://domain.com/permalink instead of just http://domain.com

How do I do this in PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it should be something like this:

```
$location = 'http:/domain.com/';
header( 'Location: ' . $location );
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution

`$variable = 'http://example.com';`
`header("Location: '" . $variable . '"');`

or

`header('Location ' . $variable);`

Comment: That first statement is kind of harsh isn't it?...

Comment: But still true. This one of the most basic things in PHP...

Comment: And while that’s true, you f*cked basic string concatenation up yourself in your answer – `"Location: ' . $variable . '"'` gives a parse error, `'Location: ' . $variable` would be correct.

Comment: And @War10ck, this user already asked a very similar question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174262/append-variable-at-end-of-url-php The least thing I expect from people asking questions here is that they actually _learn_ something from the answers they are getting, and not ask the same basic shit a month later again …

Comment: Edited it. I' ve done this on my phone in less in a minute. This was a typo and **not** a lack of knowledge.

Comment: @CBroe, thanks for the reply! This has been flagged.

Comment: @ChristianGärtner: `"Location: '" . $variable . '"'` – no syntax error any more, still wrong – the location header should look like `Location: http://example.com`, and _not_ `Location: 'http://example.com'`

Comment: Both will work, though...

Comment: Yes, and non-absolute URLs, that are often used by people, “work” as well (until with some client they don’t) … and are still wrong.

Comment: Please try to be polite. I removed the unnecessary opening to your answer. Thanks!